# Forkjoin on SwitchMap not returning after subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-observable

I am writing an Observable that will get the users from a server and am trying to improve the performance by getting only the unique users and then cacheing them. I am also using a forkjoin to update the array of users once all of the users have been returned.

First I am getting the users from the server using a service call:

```
getUsersById(user_ids: number[]): Observable<User[]> {
  return Observable.forkJoin(user_ids.map(x => this.getUserById(x)));
}
```

This uses the following function that returns an observable for the object depending on if it exists in the cache or is needed to be retrieved from the server.

```
public getUserById(user_id: number): Observable<User> {
  let tmpUser = this.users.find(x => x.id == user_id);
  if (tmpUser != null) {
    return Observable.of(tmpUser);
  } else {
    // Get Token From Cognito Session
    return this.cognito.getIdToken()
      .flatMap(token => {
      // Convert token into Header and retrieve from server
      let headers = this.getAuthHeader(token);
      return this.http
        .get(`${this.userURL}/${user_id}`, {headers: headers})
        .map((response) => response.json())
        .map(result => {
          let newUser = new User();
          newUser.deserialize(result);
          this.users.push(newUser);
          return newUser;
          });
      });
   }
}
```

The code on the component that calls the service is as follows:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if(this.reports.length != 0) {
    // Get users for reports
    let users = this.reports.map(
      x => {
        return x.user_id;
      });
    // Get unique users
    let uniqueUsers = users.filter(function (item, i, ar) {
      return ar.indexOf(item) === i;
    });
    // Make call (ForkJoin) and wait for all to return
    this.userService.getUsersById(uniqueUsers).subscribe(
      users => {
        // Add users to user array
        this.users = this.reports.map(report => {
          return users.find(user => user.id === report.user_id);
        });
        this.reportsUpdate.emit(this.reports);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is that the ForkJoin is never returning even though I can verify that the getUserById call is running to completion and returning a value. I am pretty stumped and have tried both switchmap and flatmap even though I am not entirely sure of the difference.

** EDIT **

The code for getIdToken is below

```
public getIdToken(): Observable<string> {
  return Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<string>) => {
      let cognitoUser = this.getCurrentUser();
      if (cognitoUser != null) {
        cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            observer.error(err);
          } else {
            if (session.isValid()) {
              observer.next(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        observer.error('Failed To Retrieve Id Token');
      }
    });
};

getCurrentUser() {
  return this.getUserPool().getCurrentUser();
}
```

I have confirmed that the program does hit the line:

observer.next(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());

So it does not appear that the Observer not completing is the issue

Comment: The problem is most likely that the `this.cognito.getIdToken()` observable does not complete.

Comment: I have updated my post about the contents of the cognito service and confirmed that it hits the observer.next() line. So unless I am returning incorrectly from there that does not appear to be the issue

Comment: Just realized that the next call may not be the same as completing, I have added the complete call to the getIdToken and it appears to be working now! Thanks for pushing me in the right direction to finding the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the cognito.getIdToken() call. I had written the observable that was emitting the value of the token when called. The problem is that the Observable.next() function is not the same as Observable.complete() I have added the call after and it is not working as shown below

```
public getIdToken(): Observable<string> {
  return Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<string>) => {
      let cognitoUser = this.getCurrentUser();
      if (cognitoUser != null) {
        cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            observer.error(err);
          } else {
            if (session.isValid()) {
              observer.next(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
              observer.complete(); // NEW LINE HERE!!!
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        observer.error('Failed To Retrieve Id Token');
      }
    });
};
```